# Passing values to the user control from the form in C# windows application

Tags: c#

I am developing a simple windows snake game application. I want to pass the shape type from the From and then draw it on the user controller paint method. If user select Circle i want draw a circle as the target.

**This is my drawing method**

```
public void DrawShape(Graphics paper, int shapeType)
        {
            if (shapeType == Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ShapeTypes.Rectangle))
            {
                foodRec.X = x;
                foodRec.Y = y;
                paper.FillRectangle(brush, foodRec);
            }
            if (shapeType == Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ShapeTypes.Circle))
            {
                foodCircle.X = x;
                foodCircle.Y = y;
                paper.FillEllipse(brush, foodCircle);
            }
            if (shapeType == Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ShapeTypes.Square))
            {
                foodRec.X = x;
                foodRec.Y = y;
                paper.FillRectangle(brush, foodSquare);
            }
            if (shapeType == Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ShapeTypes.Triangle))
            {

                foodTrianglePoints[0].X = x;
                foodTrianglePoints[0].Y = y;
                paper.FillPolygon(brush, foodTrianglePoints);
            }

        }
```

**This is my user controll paint method**

public int shapeType {get;set;}

```
private void GameArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            paper = e.Graphics;            
            food.DrawShape(paper, shapeType);           
            snakes.drawSnake(paper);
        }
```

I want to pass the **shapeType** from the Form 
How to do it?

Comment: may be via a propery in the user control ?

Comment: in the form  int ShapeType = 1; GameArea obj = new GameArea(ShapeType);

Comment: or obj.ShapeType = yourShapeType; of course you need your property to be accessible via the designer

Comment: I tried it but It did not work I made an  constructor In the UC like public GameArea(int shapeType)
        {
            this.shapeType = shapeType;
        }  But paint event does not fire